# Spring data method name for enum

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Is there any way to put enum value in method name with Spring Data? It can be done with `@Query` annotaion with something like this:

```
  @Query("select t from Ticket as t where t.status != desk.enums.TicketStatus.CLOSED")
  List<Ticket> findActiveTickets();
```

where status is the enum. But how can it be done with only using method names? Using something like `List<Ticket> findByStatusIsNotClosed();` will cause `No property isNotClosed found for type TicketStatus`.

So how can it be done without using `@Query`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, you can use the `default` keyword in the interface to delegate to a more generic method.

```
default List<Ticket> findActiveTickets() {
    return findByTicketStatusNotIn(ImmutableList.of(TicketStatus.CLOSED));
}

List<Ticket> findByTicketStatusNotIn(List<TicketStatus> status);
```

Comment: Use EnumSet instead of ImmutableList for the ticket status

Answer (score 0):

Currently that is not possible with Spring Data JPA. Method names are converted only using property traversal, hence the error you get. You could have a look at [specifications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications), but that would include adding another method call in your find method.

Comment: i was just wondering if it has any special syntax (some missing documentation or something). of course it can be done with specifications. it can be even done without specification just by adding status as parameter and sending status from service in method body.  i've already achieved it with using @query.